# Google Maps GMSTileDataCache ios 8 crashes in distribution mode on device, not in Simulator

Tags: ios, crash, gmsmapview

I have tried everyone else's solutions to this Google Maps problem with no success.  It runs fine in my iPad or the Simulator with distribution or development profile.   But when I send the app to hockeyapp and download from there, this is the crash.  I have redone the download of the Maps kit, rechecked the linked frameworks.  So stuck. Could it possibly be because I don't use Storyboards.

First the log:

```
May 10 17:33:37 Robert-Lissners-iPad LiveLive[169]
```

: 100 camera GMSCameraPosition 0x16d6afa0: 
target:(39.536, -119.817) bearing:0.000 zoomLevel:15.000 viewingAngle:0.000

May 10 17:33:38 Robert-Lissners-iPad LiveLive[169] 
: CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedTile' for entity 'GMSCachedTile'.
Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

May 10 17:33:38 Robert-Lissners-iPad LiveLive[169] 
: CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedObject' for entity 'GMSCachedObject'.
Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

May 10 17:33:38 Robert-Lissners-iPad LiveLive[169] 
: -[NSManagedObject tileCoords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16dbd150

Then the crash

```
May 10 17:33:38 Robert-Lissners-iPad LiveLive[169] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject tileCoords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16dbd150'
```

Incident Identifier: C2B30D45-8B91-4797-A221-D7118B71405A
    CrashReporter Key:   ba3d0208d347ef83b6002911d2c458835c96f174
    Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
    Process:             LiveLive [580]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D5902624-AB51-487A-93FC-D20BC14F5092/LiveLive.app/LiveLive
    Identifier:          com.snakebusters.LiveLive
    Version:             0.150510 (0.150510)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

```
Date/Time:           2015-05-10 17:22:47.404 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-05-10 17:22:45.421 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  6

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x24928132 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32bc3c72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2492d5f8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2492b4d4 ___forwarding___ + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2485a9d4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   LiveLive                        0x00125720 __47-[GMSTileDataCache startWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke57 + 636
6   LiveLive                        0x00129326 -[GMSTileDataCache fetchTilesImmediateWithPredicate:sortDescriptor:completionHandler:] + 410
7   LiveLive                        0x001253da __47-[GMSTileDataCache startWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 410
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3312dc7e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x331384ce _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1458
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x33137d9c _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 80
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3313a48c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 384
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3313b89e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x332afda4 _pthread_wqthread + 664
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x332afaf8 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x14da32f0
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33231164 __guarded_open_np + 24
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33220b0e guarded_open_np + 42
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32f4eaa4 0x32eac000 + 666276
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32f4e946 0x32eac000 + 665926
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32efc2fe 0x32eac000 + 328446
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32efc1b2 sqlite3_randomness + 258
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32efbfce 0x32eac000 + 327630
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32ef3e0c 0x32eac000 + 294412
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32eee80a 0x32eac000 + 272394
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32ec899a 0x32eac000 + 117146
10  libsqlite3.dylib                0x32edcaf2 0x32eac000 + 199410
11  libsqlite3.dylib                0x32edb518 sqlite3_step + 448
12  CoreData                        0x2461a85c _execute + 92
13  CoreData                        0x2461a554 -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 1844
14  CoreData                        0x246e2de4 -[NSSQLConnection prepareAndExecuteSQLStatement:] + 44
15  CoreData                        0x247019e2 -[NSSQLiteConnection _configureAutoVacuum] + 306
16  CoreData                        0x246e3864 -[NSSQLConnection createSchema] + 236
17  CoreData                        0x24616f2e -[NSSQLiteConnection connect] + 2526
18  CoreData                        0x24615e3e -[NSSQLCore _loadAndSetMetadata] + 130
19  CoreData                        0x24615c1e -[NSSQLCore loadMetadata:] + 150
20  CoreData                        0x246ce2d4 __91-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]_block_invoke + 2792
21  CoreData                        0x246da298 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 260
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x3312dc6c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x33137554 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 44
24  CoreData                        0x246cc84c _perform + 132
25  CoreData                        0x2460d09c -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 264
26  LiveLive                        0x0012006a -[GMSCacheStorage initWithName:modelBundle:modelName:directory:reset:] + 614
27  LiveLive                        0x0025c6e6 -[GMSServices initWithDisplayLink:resourceCache:] + 3246
28  LiveLive                        0x0025b258 __43-[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:]_block_invoke_2 + 104
29  LiveLive                        0x0025b194 __43-[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:]_block_invoke + 432
30  LiveLive                        0x0025afae -[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:] + 254
31  LiveLive                        0x0025ae44 -[GMSAsyncInitServices initSync] + 60
32  LiveLive                        0x0025b954 +[GMSServices sharedServicesSync] + 128
33  LiveLive                        0x0025138e -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:] + 94
34  LiveLive                        0x00250d34 -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] + 92
35  LiveLive                        0x00250c30 +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] + 68
36  LiveLive                        0x000c2500 -[LLView100 buildMapView] (LLView100.m:321)
37  LiveLive                        0x000c1ac8 -[LLView100 addToView] (LLView100.m:191)
38  LiveLive                        0x000c12f0 -[LLView100 initWithFrame:] (LLView100.m:94)
39  LiveLive                        0x000bf9a2 -[LLVC3 viewDidLoad] (LLVC3.m:70)
40  UIKit                           0x27f627a8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 596
41  UIKit                           0x27f62518 -[UIViewController view] + 20
42  UIKit                           0x27f68642 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
43  UIKit                           0x27f65fba -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 266
44  UIKit                           0x27fd10dc -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 44
45  LiveLive                        0x000ccec4 -[LLAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (LLAppDelegate.m:184)
46  UIKit                           0x27fcded0 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 368
47  UIKit                           0x281c4486 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2438
48  UIKit                           0x281c6b2a -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1402
49  UIKit                           0x281d1804 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
50  UIKit                           0x281c52e4 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 128
51  FrontBoardServices              0x2b390ebe __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 14
52  CoreFoundation                  0x248ee252 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 10
53  CoreFoundation                  0x248ed514 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
54  CoreFoundation                  0x248ec06e __CFRunLoopRun + 1710
55  CoreFoundation                  0x2483799c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
56  CoreFoundation                  0x248377ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
57  UIKit                           0x27fc7ab2 -[UIApplication _run] + 554
58  UIKit                           0x27fc2690 UIApplicationMain + 1436
59  LiveLive                        0x000d5e9a main (main.m:14)
60  libdyld.dylib                   0x3316baac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
```

Comment: i have same problem i have added "-ObjC" in other linker flag and it run sucessfully